# is there an existing openid implementation for sitefinity

Tags: openid, sitefinity

I'm just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction integrating openid with sitefinity for user creation / login for my sitefinity site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source widget you can get started with. By default it includes amazon, google, and facebook.

https://github.com/Sitefinity/Sitefinity-External-STS-Integration

You can also look into dotnetopenauth to implement your own. For example, loggin in with twitter you could create a widget that implements something like this (this is MVC which you can use in Sitefinity or you could do something similar on a button click and !IsPostback in webforms user controls.

```
    public ActionResult Login(string id)
    {
        string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        if (Request.QueryString["oauth_token"] != null)
        {
            string screenName;
            int userId;
            string profileImage;
            if (TwitterConsumer.TryFinishSignInWithTwitter(out screenName, out userId))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = screenName;
                ViewBag.UserId = userId;
               //do claims or forms auth method here.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (id == "twitter")
            {
                TwitterConsumer.StartSignInWithTwitter(false).Send();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can get more detailed instructions here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/setting-up-external-sts-login